# Gmail API generating time stamp report

Tags: api, timestamp, gmail

I am curious if I could get a report of messages sent and received that includes **time stamps and email addresses**.

I looked at the **Gmail API documentation** and I did not see anything that directly mentioned anything like that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the relevant function maybe u can see it http://imapclient.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#imapclient.IMAPClient.fetch

```
>> c.fetch([3293, 3230], ['INTERNALDATE', 'FLAGS'])
{3230: {b'FLAGS': (b'\Seen',),
    b'INTERNALDATE': datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 30, 13, 32, 9),
    b'SEQ': 84},
 3293: {b'FLAGS': (),
    b'INTERNALDATE': datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 24, 19, 30, 36),
    b'SEQ': 110}}
```